# How I model a vacuum package of meat using Blender?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

I am trying to model a "Vacuum Packed Meat without Tray Inside" package, like the ones in the following example. Packaging must have the same creases / folds as the real ones. More like the third.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have already tried to create using physics simulation and cloths, creating a large object like a cloth on the outside and a collision object on the inside and using a force with negative value (Strength: -100) within the cloth object. But the packaging does not look like it is in a vacuum. The following figures show these attempts.

[image]

Another alternative I tried was using shrinkwrap, but with this modifier the packages are without creases and without folding. And the following figures show these attempts.

[image]

What would be the best way to model this?

Can you help me ?

I'm using Blender Render Engine. 
My main intention is to recreate the folds true to the real shapes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check out Rich Colburn's rather wonderful [Modeling Cloth](https://youtu.be/jNXBYI-WPU4?t=2391) add-on. The link is to a maybe-relevant section of his instruction video.

Comment: The major problem in these cases is that the outer mesh does not wrap the inner object in the spans as it should. The outer mesh should wrap the inner mesh in each gap, in each corner, while maintaining its volume. As if the air inside the mesh had been sucked all over. And inside the mesh there is no air, so it surrounds the entire inner mesh. And inside have a piece of meat and a little bit of water.